# Approximating the average of exponential distance falloff as the exponential distance falloff of the average distance

Tags: integration, exponential-function

I have a lot of points that I want to calculate an exponential distance falloff value for, to be used in a subsurface rendering application. However, if I can perform hierarchical clustering and only evaluate this for each level it can be calculated a lot faster. To simplify, I am trying to approximate an integral of the type:

$p(x,\sigma) = \int_0^1 \exp\left(\frac{-|x-s|}{\sigma}\right) \text{d}s $

using the integral:

$q(x,\sigma) = \exp\left( -\frac{\int_0^1 |x-s| \text{d} s}{\sigma}\right) $

Where $\sigma$ would be a scattering distance, x the current location, s the location of a point in the volume. However, I cannot seem to figure out how to relate these two values correctly, as for small scattering distances there is a huge difference between them, but for long scattering distances they're about equal. I am trying to find a function $f(x,\sigma) = \frac{p(x,\sigma)}{q(x,\sigma)}$.

Any help is greatly appreciated

---

Edit:
It seems the simplification is not helping the problem, so I'll try to be more concrete at the risk of it becoming harder to explain.
I have a volume in 3d space, somewhat uniformly filled with points. The average position of all these points can be calculated once and saved for the volume. Then for any position in space I want to calculate:

$$
\mathbf{V} = \{v_1,v_2,v_3,\dots,v_n\}
$$
$$
p(x) = \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n \exp\left( -||x-v_i||_2\cdot \sigma^{-1}     \right)
$$

Of course this takes n operations to calculate. I thought perhaps I could perform a rough approximation using the average location of the points and the borders of the volume. Perhaps I should just use the minimum distance from x to any point in the volume.

Comment: Do we have $0 < x < 1$?

Comment: No we do not necessarily. It can be anywhere in space. I am actually doing this in 3d as well, but I have described it in 1d to be able to wrap my brain around the mathematics of it all

Comment: It's not immediately clear to me why the range of integration of $s$ would be $(0,1)$ then. At any rate, though, there's no simple relation between $p$ and $q$, as your problem is essentially asking "given the geometric mean of a set of numbers, find their arithmetic mean".

Comment: I'm afraid you're going nowhere as is because you formulated your question as a "XY problem". You should expose your original problem instead.

Comment: I have tried to explain the original problem. Sorry for initially formulating it in a bad way.

Comment: @ThomasConrad  The response will highly depend on the space $V$ actually. Does it have a (somewhat) specific shape (e.g. an approximated sphere) ?

Comment: Regarding the updated version of the problem: For cases where $x$ is far away from the volume (compared to the size of the volume), one can do something rather like a [multipole expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipole_expansion) of the quantity in the exponent by defining $v_i = y + z_i$, where $y$ is the average position of the points and $z_i$ is the deviation of $v_i$ from that average. What can we say about the relationship between $\sigma$ and the linear size of the volume?

Comment: @Abezhiko V is approximated by a cube. That is also the reason i used [0,1] in the integral.

Comment: @JohnBarber $\sigma$ and the size of the volume can vary quite drastically since I am using hierarchical clustering. $\sigma$ will start out vastly smaller than the volume side length. The further down the tree I go, the closer the volume size and scattering distance will come to each other and eventually $\sigma$ can become much larger than the sidelength. At that point the hierarchical approximation of the points in the volume will be close enough and I can exit.